# javascript regex to match string with and without number

Tags: javascript, regex

i'm not quite good using regex and spend two days try to fixing this problem and of course searching solutions in stackoverflow but nothing solve my problem. and here's the problem.

score variable will increased by 1 using this code

```
@inc score
```

we capture the variable using this regex

```
inc: /^@inc (.*)$/
```

and this is the argument

```
if (match.inc) {
   section = this.addAttribute(match.inc[1] + '+=1', story, section, passage, isFirst, inputFilename, lineCount);
}
```

then i try to advanced it a little more to be like this

```
@inc score 15
```

and i alter the regex

```
inc: /^@inc (.*)( )(.\d*)$/
```

and that code work fine with this alteration

```
if (match.inc) {
   section = this.addAttribute(match.inc[1] + '+=' + match.inc[3], story, section, passage, isFirst, inputFilename, lineCount);
}
```

my question is, how the regex should be? if i want keep both working

```
@inc score          <----- will increase by 1

@inc score 100000   <----- will increase by number
```

and of course how the argument should be?

here's the actual code [link](https://github.com/textadventures/squiffy/blob/master/compiler.js) line 197 and line 299

sorry for my bad english, not my mother language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure of the syntax you are using (but then, I'm not very used to javascript...), but here's a little snippet that should be able to give you some ideas:

```
var scores = ["@inc score", "@inc score 100"];

var re = /@inc score(?: (\d+))?/;

for (i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
    var inc = scores[i];

    if (result = inc.match(re)) {
        var addition = "+=" + (result[1] === undefined ? '1' : result[1]);
        alert(addition);
    }
}
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wcct7h6d/)

When the input is `"@inc score"`, the result becomes `+=1` and when it is `"@inc score 1000"`, it becomes `+=1000`.

`(?: (\d+))?` in the regex matches an optional group containing 1 space and at least 1 digit. The digits are being captured and will be the second element of the resulting list when attempting a match. This element is what is being tested at the conditional/ternary operator.

---

EDIT: Oops, to use `score` as the variable to be increased, you can use the same concept, constructed slightly differently:

```
var scores = ["@inc score", "@inc score 1000", "@inc amount 1000"];

var re = /@inc (\S+)(?: (\d+))?/;

for (i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
    var inc = scores[i];

    if (result = inc.match(re)) {
        var addition = result[1] + "+=" + (result[2] === undefined ? '1' : result[2]);
        alert(addition);
    }
}
```

I guess in your own code, it should be like:

```
inc: /^@inc (\S+)(?: (\d+))?$/
```

and

```
if (match.inc) {
   section = this.addAttribute(match.inc[1] + '+=' + (match.inc[2] === undefined ? '1' : match.inc[2]), story, section, passage, isFirst, inputFilename, lineCount);
}
```

Comment: the score variable is just example because user can use any string they want such as @inc goal, money, etc.
here's the actual code [link](https://github.com/textadventures/squiffy/blob/master/compiler.js) line 197 and line 299

Comment: @caberg Ok, I have amended the regex for the `@inc` string. And sorry, I'm not a javascript dev, but I have attempted inserting this logic in your code (answer edited).

Answer (score 1):

I would use this regex `^@inc (.*?)(?:(\s)(\d+))?$`

You can see it in action here https://regex101.com/r/dO6yN8/2.

In the first capturing group it captures everything until it sees a space (if it exists), which you wanted to be in the second capturing group for some reason, and then captures the numbers after that space in the third group. The space and numbers are optional however.

Comment: I think supporting multiple spaces is a good option `^@inc (.*?)(?:(\s+)(\d+))?$`

Comment: i think this regex is good but again, how about the argument?. here's the actual code [link](https://github.com/textadventures/squiffy/blob/master/compiler.js) line 197 and line 299
sorry for my noobness